# Werkzeug.datastructures is not a package

Tags: flask, werkzeug

I'm dealing with what I'm fairly sure is a versioning bug.

I'm running a `flask` (2.2.3) app that uses `flask-caching` (2.0.1) to cache data on Redis. I've pinned my version of `werkzeug` to 2.2.2, which is a dependency of both `flask-caching` and `flask`.

Whenever it `flask-caching` receives a cache hit and tries to pull from Redis I get the following error:

```
No module named 'werkzeug.datastructures.headers'; 'werkzeug.datastructures' is not a package
```

This happens when the underlying package `cachelib` tries to [deserialize](https://github.com/pallets-eco/cachelib/blob/main/src/cachelib/serializers.py) (line 94) the stored Redis dataset within `flask-caching`.

The pickled string comes in as

```
b'!\x80\x05\x95\x17\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x0eflask.wrappers\x94\x8c\x08Response\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94}\x94(\x8c\x08_charset\x94\x8c\x05utf-8\x94\x8c\x07headers\x94\x8c\x1fwerkzeug.datastructures.headers\x94\x8c\x07Headers\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94}\x94\x8c\x05_list\x94]\x94(\x8c\x0cContent-Type\x94\x8c\x10application/json\x94\x86\x94\x8c\x0eContent-Length\x94\x8c\x06429482\x94\x86\x94esb\x8c\x07_status\x94\x8c\x06200 OK\x94\x8c\x0c_status_code\x94K\xc8\x8c\x12direct_passthrough\x94\x89\x8c\t_on_close\x94]\x94\x8c\x08response\x94]\x94B\xaa\x8d\x06\x00{"categories":[{"is_selected":true,"key":"points","label_long":"points","label_short":"pts","multiplier":1,"punted":false,"selectable":true,"type_":"standard"},{"is_selected":true,"key":"rebounds","label_long":"rebounds","label_short":"reb","multiplier":1,"punted":false,"selectable":true,"type_":"standard"},{"is_selected":true,"key":"assists","label_long":"assists","label_short":"ast","multiplier":1,"punted":false,"selectable":true,"type_":"standard"},{"is_...
```

If you look closely `werkzeug.datastructures.headers` is included in that string it's trying to deserialize, which causes the error.

Does anyone know why this might be happening and how to approach fixing it?

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know what caused this issue, but manually clearing the cached data with `cache.clear()` seems to have stopped it from happening anymore.